# MenuBar QML QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Item {
  MenuBar {
    id: ee
    Menu {
        title: "File"
        MenuItem { text: "Open..." }
        MenuItem { text: "Close" }
    }

    Menu {
        title: "Edit"
        MenuItem { text: "Cut" }
        MenuItem { text: "Copy" }
        MenuItem { text: "Paste" }
    }
  }
}
```

**I hoped to see a menubar as an output, but I got nothing. Please point out what did I miss.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [ApplicationWindow](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-applicationwindow.html). See example there